# Initialize data of a new user in FireBase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database that looks like this:
[image]
You can think that level 1 objects are list items. And level 2 objects are corresponding list items of level 1 object. Level 1 has about 100 objects. Level 2 has about 1000 objects.

When a new user signs up, I have to initialize this structure (same for all user). Looping through all objects and saving in firebase is very slow an inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Sample code:

```
for (int i = lvl1ObjCount; i >= 1; i--) {

    String lvl1ObjKey = getLvl1KeyFromFirebase();
    setLvl1ObjInFireBase(new Level1Object(lvl1ObjKey)); 

    for (int j = lvl2ObjCount; j >= 1; j--) {
        String lvl2ObjKey = getLvl2KeyFromFirebase(lvl1ObjKey);
        setLvl2ObjInFireBase(new Level2Object(lvl1ObjKey, lvl2ObjKey));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you saying "looping through all objects and saving in firebase is very slow an inefficient"? Show us your code.

Comment: I have updated the question. It is slow because, in the app there are a lot more levels and objects have much more data. Looping through the data like this from user device crashes the app or makes the device unusable.

Comment: I'm not surprised this is slow, you should really think about [denormalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) and [avoid nesting data, flatten data structures and creating data that scales](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should flatten your data table as follows

```
{
  "users": {
       "asdfas12321": {
              "lvl1": "lvl1Key#2",
              "lvl1": "lvl1Key#2",
              },
       "asdfa112312": { ... },
       "1241dwqreq": { ... }
     }
}

{
  "lvl1": {
       "asdfas12321": {
              "lvl2": "lvl2Key#1",
              "lvl2": "lvl2Key#2",
              },
       "asdfa112312": { ... },
       "1241dwqreq": { ... }
     }
}
```